Can I trust Altium Designer Impedance Calculator over my PCB Fab?
Hello hardware people,
I'm working on 6-layer boards with impedance control.
I usually follow the standard stackup suggested by my PCB fabricator.
I am creating impedance traces for LVDS of 100 Ohm. Using Altium Designer's impedance calculator, I am getting totally different trace width and trace gap as suggested by my PCB fab.
Which one should I follow?
Should I follow the clearance from Altium and ignore the clearance from the PCB fab?

It depends what fab and what tools they're using. It would help if you share the stack-up and the calculated values from the two sources.

Do you know, and have you properly entered into altium, the exact characteristics of the PCB material used as well as its final thickness? Note that final thickness can be quite a bit different from initial thickness.

I think of this is a negotiation with the PCB house. There are multiple combinations of line width and spacing which lead to 100 ohms. I may have some preference due to escapes near an IC or other reasons, for which I'll ask the PCB house for a modification to their recommendation. At the end of the day we agree and I provide a design file which matches those agreed upon numbers, then the PCB house guarantees impedance to a tolerance such as +/-15%.  However, Altium should be somewhat in the ballpark.

In my experience, no two or more different fabricators will give he same geometries for a given controlled impedance.
They may have the same overall envelope (track + gap + track) for a differential pair.
The fabricator knows their process and although the tool in Altium is good it is no substitute for the fabricators own process and materials. The materials for PCBs are available from a number of vendors with differing attributes, so what geometries are recommended depends on that to a great extent.
This assumes both you and the vendor have agreed the stack up measurements (distance to reference is a major part of the calculation).
The answer is to use the geometries provided by the vendor including stack up measurements.
